# Button is not showing on main window even after successful execution of code in Qt

Tags: qt

I have tried this code but the button isn't displaying on the main window.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include<QGridLayout>
#include<QLabel>
#include<QPushButton>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QPushButton *l=new QPushButton();
    l->setText("abc");
    QGridLayout *q=new QGridLayout();
    q->addWidget(l);
    this->setLayout(q);
    this->show();




}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

I have tried to change the code even by passing enums for alignment but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

When you create new *Qt widgets Application*, the default form (MainWindow ui) is created with `centralWidget` to put all other widgets. In your code you created the `QGridLayout` without a parent, typically such layout should be placed in `ui->centralWidget` (as far as you are not creating another widget to be set as `centralWidget`), moreover I assume your `mainWindow` is shown from  `main.cpp` (need not use `show()`). your code could thus be:

```
QPushButton *l=new QPushButton();
l->setText("abc");
QGridLayout *q=new QGridLayout(ui->centralWidget);
q-> addWidget(l);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the widget to the GridLayout with index using addWidget function

```
void QGridLayout::addWidget(QWidget *widget, int row, int column, Qt::Alignment alignment = ...)
```

like:

```
q-> addWidget(l, 0, 0);
```

P.S. also consider using better names for your variables!